# How to make 'appendix' appear in toc in Latex?

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

How to make word 'appendix' appear in the table of contents? Right now toc looks like this:

```
1 ......  
2 ......  
.  
.  
A .....  
B .....
```

I would like it to be:

```
1 ......  
2 ......  
.  
.  
Appendix A .....  
Appendix B .....
```

My latex source file structure is like this:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{...}
\include{...}
\appendix
\include{...}
\include{...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's really not programming related, sorry!

Comment: so what kind of latex questions are valid then?

Comment: @Johannes: I disagree. SO has consistently treated LaTeX problems as programming related. This is appropriate, because TeX and LaTeX are Turing complete languages.

Comment: One might argue that in a Turing-complete document preparation system every document is a program :)

Comment: Agree, building LaTeX macros is programming.

Comment: MS Word is Turing complete (using VBA) but I hope we are not going to become Word support forum

Comment: @Neil: Really? In the standard classes this requires hacking the sectioning commands. Tell me again how that is not programming related.

Comment: In re: Word macros: if they are programming, they are in.

Comment: If so, the LaTeX is definitely programming related.  I want this question reopened, because I want to know the answer-- and hacking LaTeX is definitely programming.

Comment: My point is that because X can be programmed, not every question regarding X is necessarily programming related. In this specific case I believe the question is about markup and document structure, not programming.

Comment: You solve this by changing the definition of the \addcontentline macro. You *change* the *definition* of a *macro*. It's not markup, it's programming.

Comment: Actually, you're best off grabbing someone else's hack. But if that ruled it out, every other perl or python question, and a great many c++ questions would be out (think boost or stl).

Comment: So how do I vote to reopen?  Or do I need to play the MMO more?

Comment: @mmr: First you get another 1560ish rep, then...

Comment: We have consistently answered LaTeX questions here, I find it to be a great resource. Can we get a few more people to reopen ?

Comment: I agree we should continue to allow TeX/LaTeX questions here :)

Comment: Why is there no option to move this to tex.stackexchange.com when I vote to close it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably most easily achieved by using the [appendix
package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix?lang=en), or the [memoir class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

If you don't want to use a prepackaged solution, you'll have to
hack the sectioning commands. When I needed to do this for my
dissertation, I cloned the `report` class, and edited until I made
the margins lady happy. What you're looking for is the
definition of the `\addcontentsline` macro.

Comment: With *appendix* package, is there a way either not to use `[page]` option for *appendices* environment, or don't waste an entire page for just "Appendices" title? The problem is that when I skip `[page]`  (or `\appendixpage`), I have TOC messed up, i.e. "Appendices" comes after "Appendix A".
I guess this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661774/problem-with-adding-appendix-in-latex

Comment: @mlt It's been so long that I can't recall.

Answer (score 13):

There's a couple of ways to solve this problem; unfortunately, I've only got a hack for you at this stage. One problem is that if we redefine the section number "A" to include the word "Appendix", it messes up the formatting of the table of contents. So instead, I've just defined a new sectioning command that prints the section without a number and inserts "Appendix X" manually.

Kind of ugly, but at least it works without having to change any markup `:)`

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendix@section[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \orig@section*{Appendix \@Alph\c@section: #1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix \@Alph\c@section: #1}%
}
\let\orig@section\section
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\section\appendix@section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{goo}
\label{a} 
This is sec~\ref{a}

\section{har}
\label{b}
This is sec~\ref{b}

\appendix
\section{ji}
\label{c} 
This is app~\ref{c}
\subsection{me}
does this look right?

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I use that hack with `\asbuk` using `fontspec`? I need russian appendix numberings.

Comment: Adobe, I can't paste code here. I've posted my solution in the separate answer. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Will, this works like magic! However, I get a strange side effect: the references (if you add them) are transformed into a new section Appndix B*. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Just replace all `section` with `chapter` if your appendix is by chapters

Answer (score 13):

For my thesis, I did the following:

```
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix~\ref{app:scripts}: Training Scripts}
\section*{Sample Training Scripts}
\label{app:scripts}
Blah blah appendix content blah blah blah.
```

Explanation: I manually added a line to the TOC so I would have "Appendix X:..." show up in my TOC. Then I excluded the actual section command from the TOC by using an asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

The appendix package is really good and simple solution. My answer can be helpful for who wants to change chapters numbering style, for example, with using cyrillic alphabet or roman digits. The appendices numbering style is hardcoded in the \@resets@pp command (I looked in sources here http://hal.in2p3.fr/docs/00/31/90/21/TEX/appendix.sty). I solved it by simple redefining this command to my own. Just add this code into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter

    \renewcommand{\@resets@pp}{\par
        \@ppsavesec
        \stepcounter{@pps}
        \setcounter{section}{0}

        \if@chapter@pp
            \setcounter{chapter}{0}
            \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}
            \gdef\thechapter{\Asbuk{chapter}} % changed
        \else
            \setcounter{subsection}{0}
            \gdef\thechapter{\Asbuk{section}} % changed
        \fi

        \if@pphyper
            \if@chapter@pp
                \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\theH@pps.\Asbuk{chapter}} % changed
            \else
                \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\theH@pps.\Asbuk{section}} % changed
            \fi

            \def\Hy@chapapp{\appendixname}%
        \fi
    \restoreapp
}

\makeatother
```

As a result,

```
Appendix A
Appendix B
Appendix C
...
```

will change to

```
Appendix A
Appendix Б
Appendix В
... etc
```

I'm not a latex expert, and I can't guarantee this code won't break something else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Will Robertson's answer, the code below defines the same thing but for chapter and also fixes the fact that `chapter*` does not add to the header when using the `fancyhdr` package.

With this in the preable all issues are resolved.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendix@chapter[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \def\app@ct{Appendix \@Alph\c@chapter: #1}
    \orig@chapter*{\app@ct}%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\app@ct}%
}
\let\orig@chapter\chapter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\chapter\appendix@chapter}
\makeatother
```