# Add "Appendix" before "A" in thesis TOC

Tags: latex

I am required to insert the word Appendix before the letter A in my dissertation Table of Contents as follows:

Appendix A (title for appendix A)

but the latex thesis cls file I use generates only the letter A followed by the appendix title:

A (title for appendix A)

The thesis cls file defines a "backmatter" command and the appendix is treated as a chapter.

```
\newcommand\backmatter{\appendix
\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{%
\ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}{%
\ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}}%
\def\sectionmark##1{\relax}}
```

Is there a simple fix to the above code that will add the word Appendix before the letter A in the TOC for Appendix A?  There is a related question, [How to make 'appendix' appear in toc in Latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717316/how-to-make-appendix-appear-in-toc-in-latex), but the answers did not appear to help in this case.

Comment: this would be better at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you want using the `appendix` package. Here's a sample file that shows you how. The key is the `titletoc` option when calling the package. It takes whatever value you've defined in `\appendixname` and the default value is `Appendix`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
  \chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like

[image]

Comment: I used your solution and it looks the same, but clicking a hyperlink on an appendix brings me to the document's first page. Hyperlinks on other chapters - generated by `\tableofcontents` - work fine. Could you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know, that I am supposed to add `\appendix` before the actual chapter, ehm.

Comment: Sometimes `hypertexnames=false` as parameter at `hyperref` helps.

Comment: This only adds Appendix before A in the TOC, but not where the section actually starts

Comment: @smihael In order to add Appendix before A in the section as well, use 

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

instead of only 

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

Comment: You also have to get rid of the default `\appendix` command, and use the `\begin{appendices} [...] \end{appendices}` environment instead.